# Semipartial correlation forcing independent contribution

Tags: time-series, correlation

I compute semipartial correlations between 4 source/seed time-series and 1000 target time-series. e.g., seeds 2-4 are partialled out of seed 1 before computing the correlations.

My goal is to quantify the unique contribution of each seed to the correlation with each target.

The problem is the following criticism I have recently received in a peer-review:

"the approach the authors have taken is forcing the contribution of different seeds to be independent. Isn't the question whether there are independent contributions?"

The question is, am I really 'forcing' the contribution to be independent or merely testing if it is so?

Thank you for your time.
Sami